# Abstract class method is never used

Tags: java

Say I have the following classes:

```
abstract class A {
  abstract public void methodA();
}

class B extends A {
  @Override
  public void methodA(){
  }
}
```

And then I use `methodA()` somewhere else with implementation of class `B`. In Android Studio, when I opened class `A` in editor, it gave me the warning that `method methodA() is never used`. Why is that so?

Comment: it shouldn't warn in this particular code, are you sure method is `public` and not `private` ?

Comment: Because it does static checking and determines you don't have any concrete classes calling that method in class A. It doesn't look anywhere else, just class A. It's a warning, and in this case you can ignore it. Although, I cannot reproduce that in my local eclipse.

Comment: Yes I have just double-checked, all methods are `public`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch hmm but it knows that `methodA()` in class `B` has been used, because it doesn't give me any warning when I opened class `B` in editor

Comment: @user3386238 Knows is a verb that signifies intellect, it knows nothing (like Jon Snow). It can only be a heuristic algorithm.